# NPM does not install dependencies

Tags: npm, npm-install

There are a handful of other questions on here, but none that seem to be the same problem.

Running `npm install` on a preexisting `package.json`, pulled in from git, does all of its processing, creates a `node_modules` directory, then ends without installing the modules. `node_modules` is empty, and there were no errors (just a couple warnings about deprecated modules). The entire directory is owned by the active user.

After a bunch of messing around, I've found that if I remove all of the `devDependencies`, the normal dependencies will install as expected.

OS: `Ubuntu 16.04`

Node: `6.9.1`

NPM: `3.10.8`

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --ignore src --ignore public --ignore views",
    "test": "node ../app.js"
  },
  "author": "xxx",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^13.1.1",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "event-stream": "^3.3.4",
    "fs-extra": "^1.0.0",
    "git-guppy": "^1.2.1",
    "glob": "^7.1.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-duration": "0.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-function": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-git": "^1.12.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^6.2.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "guppy-pre-commit": "^0.4.0",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^2.8.0",
    "postcss-math": "0.0.5",
    "precss": "^1.4.0",
    "q": "^1.4.1",
    "utils-merge": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.2",
    "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "git-rev-sync": "^1.8.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta6",
    "yamljs": "^0.2.8"
  }
}
```

This is running on a basic DO server, the same distribution I've spun up for a dozen other projects, with no problem. The only thing I can think of is if there's something within one of the devDependencies that is clogging things up. How to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that "fs" is not a valid ***npm*** package.   I came to this conclusion after running this command:

```
npm bugs fs
```

This ended up displaying bugs filed against a [npm/security-holder](https://github.com/npm/security-holder) package.   It appears that the "fs" on NPM may have been malicious.

If you want ***node's [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) package***, you don't need an entry in your package.json for that, fs is built-in.